# Search function in python using tree view not working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, search, treeview

The search for displaying the records:

```
def SearchCustomer(self):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("Guestrecord.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    columnID = ["title","firstName","surname","dob","payment","email","address","postcode"]
    columnStr =["Title","FirstName","Surname","DOB","Payment","Email","Address","Postcode"]

    self.search_table = ttk.Treeview(self.search_frame,columns=columnID,show="headings")

    self.search_table.bind("<Motion>","break")

    for i in range(0,8):
        self.search_table.heading(columnID[i],text = columnStr[i])
        self.search_table.column(columnID[i],minwidth = 0, width = 108)
    self.search_table.place(x=20,y=0)

    for GuestRec in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tb1Guest1"):
        self.search_table.insert("",END,values=GuestRec)

    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
SearchCustomer(self)

search_icon = Image.open("search icon.png")
search_icon_resize = search_icon.resize((20,20))
search_icon = search_icon_resize
search_icon_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(search_icon)


self.search_firstname = Entry(self.search_frame2, width=30,bg="#e2f0d9",font=("Avenir Next",18),highlightthickness = 0,relief=FLAT)
self.search_firstname.place(x = 140, y =0)
self.search_firstname_label = Label(self.search_frame2,bg = "white", text = "First Name", font=("Avenir Next",20))
self.search_firstname_label.place(x= 20,y=0)
self.search_Surname = Entry(self.search_frame2, width=30,bg="#e2f0d9",font=("Avenir Next",18),highlightthickness = 0,relief=FLAT)
self.search_Surname.place(x = 140, y =40)
self.search_Surname_label = Label(self.search_frame2,bg = "white", text = "Surname", font=("Avenir Next",20))
self.search_Surname_label.place(x= 20,y=40)
searchButton = Button(self.search_frame2, image=search_icon_photo,height = 35, width =35, command=self.Search,bg ="white")
searchButton.place(x= 500, y = 0)
```

The actual search function which his not working when trying to display the results:

```
def Search(self):
    connection = sqlite3.connect("Guestrecord.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    sFirst_Name = self.search_firstname
    sSurname = self.search_Surname
    search_rec = (sFirst_Name,sSurname)

    search_rec_new = tuple(item for item in search_rec if item !="")
    search_fields = ["sFirst_Name","sSurname"]

    search_SQL = "SELECT * FROM tb1Guest1 WHERE guestID LIKE '%'"

    for i in range(len(search_rec)):
        if search_rec[i] != "":
             search_SQL += "AND" + search_fields[i] + "LIKE '%' || ? || '%'"
    # Clearing search results
    for rec in self.search_table.get_children():
        self.search_table.delete(rec)

    #Display the records 

    for GuestRec in cursor.execute(search_SQL,search_rec_new):
        self.search_table.insert("",END,values=GuestRec)

    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

The error message that prints out afterwards:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidgets/button_base.py", line 893, in cmd
    self.cnf['command']()
  File "/Users/pearcemaguire/Documents/Course work for bed and breakfast cs/Bed and breakfast database take two .py", line 987, in Search
    for GuestRec in cursor.execute(search_SQL,search_rec_new):
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ANDsFirst_NameLIKE": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces between `AND`, your search field and `LIKE`:
`search_SQL += " AND " + search_fields[i] + " LIKE '%' || ? || '%'"`

See the error you are getting: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ANDsFirst_NameLIKE": syntax error` → it means that the SQL you are sending to the database is "ANDsFirst_NameLIKE" instead of "AND sFirst_Name LIKE" → that is because you forgot about the spaces when creating that SQL statement.